# how to play video using terminal on ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, video-player, terminal-server

A few days before, I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 on my android, but it has no gui so I can't play video. Is there is any way to play video using terminal?

Comment: To do this you need mplayer with the option:

 mplayer -vo caca /path/to/the/video

Or mplayer -vo fbdev /path/to/the/video (to show the output on framebuffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install mplayer:

```
sudo aptitude install mplayer

mplayer *  #for multiple files
```

OR

```
mplayer -vo fbdev -fs <video.avi>
```

Comment: How on hell will he play videos with VLC without a GUI?

Comment: Aah ! its my mistake .